# How do I wrap blocks of li elements in ul elements

Tags: php, regex, dom, string, html-parsing

Okay considering having the following sample string.

```
Duis posuere suscipit lacus quis lacinia. In molestie lectus sed.
<li>test line here</li>
<li>Second test</li>
<li>Third test</li>
<li>Another test</li>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis posuere suscipit lacus quis lacinia. In molestie lectus sed.
\* Aliquam posuere sapien id elit sodales at vestibulum lacus porttitor. 
*hej
A * hejdu
<li>hejsan</li>
<li>Another item</li>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipidsa
<li>Lonely list item</li>
```

So lets say I want to wrap the three *li blocks* in ul elements so I'll have the four first li elements wrapped in one ul, the two elements in the 2nd block wrapped in one ul and the last one wrapped in one ul. I'm thinking regex but I don't know quite how I'd build up such a regex. Maybe there's some other option?

Comment: you can use JavaScript to acheive this

Comment: If you say php - what format or structure is your data in? Do you want to parse many badly formatted html files? Couldn't you search/replace?

Comment: Yeah I bet you can but that isn't a good solution in my case. I see no reason to run a javascript for hundreds of visitors every day when it can be done once with php on the server-side. Also it's better standards wise to have them wrapped in a UL to begin with, all browsers might not have javascript or the user might have disabled it.

@Martin: I fetch badly formated html from a external source then I parse it on the server-side and make it more well formatted before inserting it in the database so that the users visiting the site sees the good html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a source transformation, then a regular expression might be an option It depends on the format being consistent. But then you could use something like:

```
= preg_replace("#(^<li>.*?</li>\s*)+#m", "<ul>$0</ul>", $content);
```

The trick is looking for something that can occour multiple times with `(...)+` while the inner part is restricted to exact matches `<li>..</li>` which even requires to be at the `^` start of a line.

There might be other options. But I cannot imagine how to wrap li-groups with DOM methods, since you start out with a text document.

Comment: Seems to do what I want but may I ask what the # instead of / does?

Comment: @Hultner: It's a laziness delimiter. You can enclose regular expressions in any ASCII character. `/..*/` is the same as `#..*#` or `!..*!`. So you can use any and thus avoid \ escaping if `/` is used within the search expression and not as enclosure.

Comment: Ohh I see that's quite smart but confusing for someone who aren't too experienced with regex, anyway thanks a lot. I guess I'll learn all these little tricks over time. I also though that DOM methods would be a problem since it isn't properly formatted xml/html to begin with.